# Prove by induction that for $q\neq1$, we have $1+q+...+q^{n-1}=\dfrac{q^{n}-1}{q-1}, \forall n\in \mathbb N $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

### Prove by induction that for $q\neq1$, we have $1+q+...+q^{n-1}=\dfrac{q^{n}-1}{q-1}, \forall n\in \mathbb N $

Let $P(n)$ be the proposition we want to prove.

For $P(1)$ we have:
$q^0=\dfrac{q^1-1}{q-1}\implies1=1$, so $P(1)$ is true

For $P(2)$ we have:
$q^0+q^1=\dfrac{q^2-1}{q-1}\implies1+q=1+q$, so $P(2)$ is true

**Inductive Hypothesis:** Let $n=k$ and we assume that $P(k):1+q+...+q^{k-1}=\frac{q^{k}-1}{q-1}$ is true .

We have to prove that $P(k+1):1+q+...+q^{k-1}+q^{k}=\dfrac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}$ is true.

**Inductive step:** $1+q+...+q^{k-1}+q^{k}=\dfrac{q^{k}-1}{q-1}+q^{k}$,

And I get stuck at this part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{q^k-1}{q-1}+q^k=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}
$$

Comment: Could you explain me a Little bit more that step? thank you very much¡

Comment: $\frac{q^k-1}{q-1}+q^k=\frac{q^k-1+q^k(q-1)}{q-1}=\frac{q^k-1+q^{k+1}-q^k}{q-1}=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}.$

Answer (score 1):

Assume it for $k$ and we show the formula for $k+1$:

$1+q+...+q^{k}+q^{k+1}=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}+q^{k+1}=\frac{q^{k+1}-1+q^{k+1}(q-1)}{q-1}=\frac{q^{k+1}-1+q^{k+2}-q^{k+1}}{q-1}=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{q^k-1}{q-1} + q^k = \frac{q^k-1 + (q-1)q^k}{q-1} = \frac{q^{k+1} + q^k - q^k - 1}{q-1} = \frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}$